# How to use classroom service with GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-classroom

The sample code https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/android shows how to invoke the service when using GoogleAcccountCredential class to sign-in to google.

```
    mService = new com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Kindergarten Math School")
            .build();
```

But, with newer release of  we are now using play-services-auth, we are now using a GoogleApiClient. How do we create the service with it?

Answer (score 0):

Every request your application sends to the Classroom API must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google. You can either use [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/#google-sign-in) or [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

Using classroom.googleapis.com have different services available like [.courses](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses). You can create a course by using the service.

HTTP request

```
POST https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses

{
"id": string,
"name": string,
"section": string,
"descriptionHeading": string,
"description": string,
"room": string,
"ownerId": string,
"creationTime": string,
"updateTime": string,
"enrollmentCode": string,
"courseState": enum(CourseState),
"alternateLink": string,
"teacherGroupEmail": string,
"courseGroupEmail": string,
"teacherFolder": {
object(DriveFolder)
},
"courseMaterialSets": [
{
object(CourseMaterialSet)
}
],
}
```

Requires he following OAuth scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses

For more details regaridng Classroom API, check this link: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/

Answer (score 0):

So, I made the following changes -

Added the dependency back in build.gradle -

```
schoolCompile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {  
  exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'  
}
```

Then, created the credential object alongside the googleApiClient

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)  
      .requestIdToken(activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_client_id))  
      .requestEmail()  
      .requestProfile()  
      .requestScopes(new Scope(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY), new Scope(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_ROSTERS_READONLY))  
      .requestServerAuthCode(auth_client_id)  
      .build();  


mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)  
  .enableAutoManage(activity /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)  
  .addConnectionCallbacks(this)  
   //.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)  
   .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)  
  .build();  

mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(  
  activity.getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))  
  .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```

Did the sign-in using mGoogleApiClient -

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);  
activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

When that completes (in onActivityResult), set the email on the credential -

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);  
if (result.isSuccess()) {  
   // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.  
   GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();  
   mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(acct.getEmail());  
} else {  
   // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.  
   Log.i("GoogleAuthHelper", "Log in failed:"+result.getStatus());  
}
```

Use the credential when connecting to classroom to create the service as before -

```
HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();  
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();  
mService = new com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom.Builder(  
  transport, jsonFactory, credential)  
  .setApplicationName("Kindergarten Math School")  
  .build();
```

And, that worked. During sign-in, I was asked to authorize the additional classroom scopes. And the classroom calls went through successfully. Still cleaning up the above code, but, it works!

Comment: Where you set the selected account, you can also use:
mCredential.setSelectedAccount( acct.getAccount() );
It really does the same thing, but might be a little more readable.

Comment: I think there was some permissioning issue with using setSelectedAccount instead of setSelectedAccountName. May be fixed now. Worth a try.